# How do i set the size of an array based on a parameter of a method in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm new to OOP and classes so I might be overlooking something simple.
I have some code working to draw a grid on the GUI, but if I want to change the size of the grid I need to change the code which isn't ideal since I want multiple grids to be shown within a single program.

The following code correctly sets up my variables and array for my "draw grid" code to generate a 50x50 grid:

```
public Board(int gridSize) {
    int size = gridSize;
}

//dimensions of grid
private int size;
private const int sizeOfBox = 5;
private const int space = 2;
bool[,] boxes = new bool[50, 50];
```

(after that i have a Draw method)

But if I were to change the line  `"bool[,] boxes = new bool[50, 50];"` to  `"bool[,] boxes = new bool[size, size];"` i get errors saying "A field initialiser cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Board.size'" and I don't know how to fix it.

tl;dr i need a way to set the dimensions of a 2d array to be equal to a constructor's paramter by the same parameter (10 by 10, 50 by 50 etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the array to be the size you receive in the constructor, then you have to set it in the constructor:

```
public class Board {
    public Board(int gridSize) {
        size = gridSize;
        boxes = new bool[gridSize, gridSize];
    }

    //dimensions of grid
    private int size;
    private const int sizeOfBox = 5;
    private const int space = 2;
    bool[,] boxes;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help! not sure why i hadn't tried this :P